# Django does not render my forms' fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have this model in models.py:

```
class Life_events(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
HSCT_date = models.DateField('HSCT date',null=True,blank=True)
HSCT_outcome = models.CharField('HSCT outcome',max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
partaker_in_clinical_trial= models.CharField('Partaker in clinical trial',max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
date_of_input= models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.patient)
```

My forms.py contains:

```
class LifeEventsForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LifeEventsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper=FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
         Fieldset (
            '<b>HSCT</b>',
            Div(
                #HTML(u'<div class="col-md-2"></div>'),
                Div('HSCT_date',css_class='col-md-6'),
                Div('HSCT_outcome',css_class="col-md-6"),
                Div('partaker_in_clinical_trial', css_class='col-md-6'),
                css_class='row',
                ),
         ),

         FormActions(
            Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
            Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
        ),
    )
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.form_show_labels = True

class Meta:
    model = Life_events
    exclude = ['patient', 'date_of_input']
```

My views.py has:

```
my_life_ev = LifeEventsForm(prefix='life_ev')
 return render_to_response('input.html', {'frm_life_ev': my_life_ev,}, context)
```

And my template file input.html has:

```
  {%crispy frm_life_ev%}
```

When I render my template I can't see the form fields but only the word 'HSCT' which I have in Fieldset. My html code does not contain the fields at all.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form inherits from `forms.Form`, which does not know anything about models and ignores the Meta class. You should inherit from `forms.ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a ModelForm. A simple Form won't do.

```
class LifeEventsForm(forms.ModelForm)
```